# Computing a mathematical expression using half and full adders

Tags: digital-logic, adder

I am new to logical desing and I am not sure how to start the exercise.

The problem:

> Assume that we have 2 assinged numbers of 2 bits (A = a1 a0 and B = b1
>   b0). Desing a combinational logical circuit that computes the S = 4A +
>   3B and uses half and full adders, only.

What I am thinking is to use 2 full adders to compute the "4 * A", another 2 to compute the "3 * B" and another one to compute the S = 4A + 3B. This mean that I will need 5 full adders in total.

Is this the best and most efficient solution? I guess no but I can't think something better.

Is this diagram right?

[image]

Comment: Probably not the most optimal solution, but it does the job. And I even believe that is what you are actually required to do. The more advanced solution would be to try to come up with a Boolean function for the expression and try to implement it using adders only. There is no formal method for that. And the result is not guaranteed to be different from the naive one.

Comment: However you decide to approach it remember that you don't have to do anything to multiply a number by 4, just "shift" it twice. Or in other words just wire the value into position 2 bits higher than it started.  11b multiplied by 4 is just 1100b (added two zeros).

Comment: ... And `3B` is the same as `B+2B`, while `2B` is shifting as well. So.. looks like you can get away with just two adders :)

Comment: @EugeneSh. Yes shifting could do the job but in order to be able to shift the number don't I need to implement something like Shift Register with D-Flip Flops and a clock? I can't use a clock or a D-Flip Flop

Comment: @George, shifting by a fixed amount can be as simple as just connecting the a1 and a0 inputs to the a3 and a2 inputs of the next adder.

Comment: @ThePhoton That's right but in order to do that I will need a 4 bits and A has only 2? I am a little bit confused..

Comment: How many bits `S` is required to be? Well, in above comment I missed the point that FA's and HA are one bit only

Comment: @EugeneSh., I think more than 2 (one-bit) adders are needed to account for all the required carries.

Comment: @ThePhoton Yeah, see my previous comment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, realize that multiplying a binary number by a power of 2 can be done by simply shifting the number, and no adders are required. Also, 3B can be written as 2B + B.

So your required calculation becomes

```
     a1 a0  0  0    (4 A)
           b1 b0    (B)
+       b1 b0  0    (2 B)
----------------
  s4 s3 s2 s1 s0
```

If you notice that it doesn't require an adder to add 0 to something, you can simplify this to

```
     a1 a0 b1 b0    (4 A + B)
+       b1 b0  0    (2 B)
----------------
  s4 s3 s2 s1 s0
```

I believe this can be implemented with 2 half-adders and one full-adder, but I'll leave it to you to work out how and to draw it as a schematic diagram.

Comment: Nice. Even easier than it looked at first..

Comment: Yes. Two HA and one FA can achieve it. +1!

Comment: Thanks for the answer, this way sounds more efficient. I am having a hard time implementing the schematic diagram. Will I need to use something that represents memory like a flip flop? Otherwise how will i remeber the last value to do Val = New_Val + Last_Val.

Comment: The resulting expression above is a simple addition. Why would it require memory? It is implemented as asked - using a bunch of adders only

Comment: Because I can't give the whole number at once but 1 bit everytime, right?

Comment: Why? Is it stated in the question? I read it as having all of the input in parallel.

Comment: @George, you're asked to "desing a combinational logical circuit". If the data are arriving serially instead of in parallel, I don't think this is possible. If you use flip-flops (or make them out of logic) you would be violating this part of the requirements.

Comment: You are right, it must be a combinational circuit. I updated my post with the possible diagram. Is it correct?

Comment: @George, you said A is a 2-bit number, but you only show it as one bit in your diagram. And your output will need to be 5 bits to allow for all 2-bit values of A and B, but your diagram only has two wires that look like outputs.

Comment: @ThePhoton So I need 1 input per bit. This mean in order to represent both A and B I will need 4 bits in total, 2 per variable. Right?  My main problem is how to convert a1 a0 to (a1 a0 b1 b0) with just one half adder. I mean I think I can do it with 4 FA but not with 1.
http://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/combination/comb34.gif

Comment: You don't need any adders or half adders to do that. Just connect a1 to where a1 needs to be added to something else,connect b1 to where b1 needs to be added to something else, and so on.

Comment: Hint: each **column** in the sums in my answer corresponds to a possible (half or full) adder.

Comment: @ThePhoton Check again. I think i got it!!!!! It's hard until you do it. Thanks!!

Comment: @George, it looks right, but it would be easier to tell if you labelled the inputs.

Comment: It's from top to botton b0, b1, a0, a1.